# Typescript Library index.d.ts not used in other typescript application

Tags: typescript

Apologies in advance I'm going to attempt to explain this the best I can but please bear with me.

I've created a library that is then installed via npm into a typescript Vue project. However try as I might the types (even though it comes with a index.d.ts file) are not been pulled through and I get a `Module '"../../node_modules/[library name]/dist"' has no exported member [exported member]` error.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the tsconfig.json for the library:

```
// library tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "node_modules/@types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "typeRoots": ["src/types/**/*", "node_modules/@types"]
}
```

And the package.json for the library

```
  "name": "LIBRARY NAME",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
     ...
   }
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged && concurrently npm:test npm:lint"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14.15.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.0"
  },
// deps etc etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was a VSCode error. I completely closed and reopened my VSCode and it started to pickup the type declarations even when using npm link to my library.